# R - Create table,how much of a vector in % is contained in another vector

Tags: r

I have a number of vectors containing a set of numbers.

e.g.:

```
v1 <- c(15,12,50,2007,1828)
v2 <- c(50,2007,11,8)
```

in the next step i Want to see how much of vector 2 in Percent is contained in vector 1

```
sim <- length(which(v2%in%v1 ==T)) / length(v2)
```

I created a for loop for that ,checking v1 versus v2,v3,v4.... and then v2 versus v1,v3,4... 
If the sim value was bigger than 10% i wanted to enter that in a table.

Because of the number of vectors ~ 1000. The for loop is taking way to long.
Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Instead of `which` I would use `intersect` in your case. Further I would recommend to use `sapply` instead of a for loop or initialize an empty results object and fill it during the loop, otherwise the loop is very slow. Does that help already?

Comment: Also, you might vectorize part of your problem by creating a "data matrix" and check vector occurrence in the whole matrix in one call.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the set operator `intersect`

First, calculate the intersection of the two vectors

```
shared <- intersect(v1,v2)
```

Next, calculate the percent of shared elements in `v2`

```
sim <- length(shared)/length(v2)
```

If you type `?intersect` in your R command line, you will see there are also other helpfull setoperations like `union` and `setdiff`